# I want to convert below for loop into array.map() but not sure how to

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

OtpInput is another component and OTPLength is props obtained from parent component and is neccessary.

```
{
    const otp = getOtpValue()
    const inputs = []

    for (let index = 0; index < OTPLength; index++) {
      inputs.push(
        <Input
          key={index}
          focus={activeInput === index}
          value={otp[index]}
          onChange={handleOnChange}
          onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown}
          onInput={handelOnInput}
          onInputFocus={onInputFocus}
          index={index}
          secure={secure}
          invalid={invalid}
          autoFocus={autoFocus}
        />
      )
    }

    return inputs
}
```

Have tried and changed the below way , but i am getting only one input instead of the value passed in OTPLength as props and then used to create a new Array based on OTPLength .

```
const renderInputs = useMemo(() => {
    const otp = getOtpValue()
    const inputs = new Array(OTPLength)
    return [...inputs].map((_,index) =>
            <Input
                key={index}
                focus={activeInput === index}
                value={otp[index]}
                onChange={handleOnChange}
                onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown}
                onInput={handelOnInput}
                onInputFocus={onInputFocus}
                index={index}
                secure={secure}
                invalid={invalid}
                autoFocus={autoFocus}
              />
            )
  }, [
    getOtpValue,
    OTPLength,
    activeInput,
    handleOnChange,
    handleOnKeyDown,
    handelOnInput,
    onInputFocus,
    autoFocus,
    invalid,
    secure
  ])
```

Comment: You can create an `Array` with `OTPLength` and map. `[...Array(OTPLength)].map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over an *empty* `Array()`, the *second* parameter of `map()` refers to the current index

```
    const myArray = [...new Array(OTPLength)].map((obj, i)=> (
      <Input
        key={index}
        focus={activeInput === i}
        value={otp[i]}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown}
        onInput={handelOnInput}
        onInputFocus={onInputFocus}
        index={index}
        secure={secure}
        invalid={invalid}
         autoFocus={autoFocus}
       />
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need `map()`, you may simply do:

```
const inputs = Array.from({length: OTPLength}, (_,i) => 
    <Input 
        key={i} 
        focus={activeInput == i} 
        /* the rest of your props */ 
    />
)
```

Or, if you still prefer `map()`:

```
const inputs = [...Array(OTPLength)].map((_,i) => 
    <Input 
        key={i} 
        focus={activeInput == i} 
        /* the rest of your props */ 
    />
)
```

Comment: IMHO it's a wise choice to use triple equals `===` when comparinga values. Otherwise if *activeInput* would be *[]* or *false* or *[null]* or *''* item 0 will be  focused anyway. The most of the linter configuration would also advise you about that.

Comment: It's not that I promote lazy typing, but I prefer to keep my solution *dry* as long as it reaches the major goal. So, I assumed that implicit type conversion is not the case for state variables here.

Comment: I've pointed out it mainly because triple equals are present in original OP code and may raise an issue if removed

Comment: ...*'may raise an issue'* or may not, however, my personal rule is validating data as it *enters* the app rather than stacking all sorts of proof reading all along the way

Comment: Sources such as D. Crockford and MDN both advise that only triple equals operator should be used when programming in JavaScript and double equals operator be ignored altogether. Also you have to take in account that on the same codebase could be worked by several _devs_, and also this could rise a critical issue while coding in a team. That's what is called "bad practice". I also want to point out as last thing that above mentioned D. Crockford is the _author_ of javascript language, so it's quite reliable.

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
const renderInputs = useMemo(() => {
const otp = getOtpValue()
const inputs = new Array(OTPLength)
let ret = inputs.map((_,index) =>
        <Input
            key={index}
            focus={activeInput === index}
            value={otp[index]}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown}
            onInput={handelOnInput}
            onInputFocus={onInputFocus}
            index={index}
            secure={secure}
            invalid={invalid}
            autoFocus={autoFocus}
          />
        );
        return ret;
 }, [
getOtpValue,
OTPLength,
activeInput,
handleOnChange,
handleOnKeyDown,
handelOnInput,
onInputFocus,
autoFocus,
invalid,
secure
])
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code creates an array the same size as OTPLength and returns an array of Input elements

```
let otpArray = new Array(OTPLength);
return [...otpArray].map((element, index) => (
   <Input
       key={index}
       focus={activeInput === index}
       value={otp[index]}
       onChange={handleOnChange}
       onKeyDown={handleOnKeyDown}
       onInput={handelOnInput}
       onInputFocus={onInputFocus}
       index={index}
       secure={secure}
       invalid={invalid}
       autoFocus={autoFocus}
   />
))
```

Comment: Have tried all the below answers but i am getting only one input element instead of the value passed in OTPLength , Have updated my code

Comment: what is OTPLength? is it a number? or an object?